# Deploy war file parse error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, web-deployment, wildfly-8

I would like to deploy a Java web application on Wildfly 8.1.0, previously it was deployed on JBoss 5.  The JDK version is 1.7.0_25, I use Oracle ADF version 11, and during deployment I have the following error

```
09:19:06,804 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyAppServer.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyAppServer.war".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "MyAppServer.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017302: Failed to parse XML descriptor "/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/MyAppServer.war/WEB-INF/lib/adf-richclient-impl-11.jar/META-INF/afu.tld" at [1560,10]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.parseTLD(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:232)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.processTlds(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:206)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:144)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some Oracle ADF versions out there contain invalid **tld** files. The same problem has been reported on various forums:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/200842
https://community.jboss.org/thread/199792

The problem might be fixed in more recent versions, but if it's not possible for you to upgrade, you can fix the **tld** file (`adf-richclient-impl-11.jar/META-INF/afu.tld`) yourself by removing the offending HTML tags from the `description` elements.

In your case, the first invalid element seems to appear on line 1560.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already have a look at this? https://community.jboss.org/thread/199792